# PHP arrays from form input

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, associative

I have some data in a html table which has been populated from a mysql database.  To put the data into the html table I have done the following:

```
$meterdetail = getMeterDetails($ticketNumber);
```

This gets a number of records from the mysql table  Then for each record retrieved from the db I do the following..

```
foreach ($meterdetail as $v2) {
<tr>
    <td class='tableText'>
        <input type='hidden' name='ids[]' value='".$v2['id']."'>
        <input type='text' name='meters[]' value=''>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Ultimately what I am trying to do here is update each record (based on the ID from the mysql table) with the values in the input of the table.

When I click on a submit button I need to step through each record that was collected and insert the value that was typed into the html form corresponding to the relevant id.

To process the $_POST data I do the following

```
if (!empty($_POST['meters']) && !empty($_POST['ids'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['meters']); $i++) {
        updateRecord($_POST['ids'][$i],$_POST['meters'][$i]);
    }
}
```

This seems to be working but for some reason I don't feel comfortable with this solution so my question is:  Is there a better (more elegant / more correct) way to do this (particularly the processing of the 2 $_POST arrays)?  Can I create one associative array with the ID as key and the form input value as the corresponding value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$met = $_POST['meters'];
$id = $_POST['ids'];



if (isset($met) && isset($id)) 
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++) 
    {
        updateRecord($id[$i],$met[$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ... although this is almost identical to what I have .. Is there not a way I can do something like $_POST['id']['meter'] where id1 => meter_reading for each id..?

Comment: yes thats true, but truley what you are doing is a optimal solution w.r.t split time

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to make sure you have 'set in stone' names for your inputs;

```
foreach ($meterdetail as $key => $v2) {
    echo "
<tr>
    <td class='tableText'>
        <input type='hidden' name='id_".$key."' value='".$v2['id']."'>
        <input type='text' name='meter_".$key."' value=''>
    </td>
</tr>
    ";
}
```

And than process the post-data as such:

```
$ids = array();
$meters = array();
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    if(strpos($name, 'id_') === 0) {
        $ids[substr($name, 3)] = $value;
    }
    if(strpos($name, 'meter_') === 0) {
        $ids[substr($name, 3)] = $value;
    }
}

if(count($ids) && count($meters)) {
    foreach($ids as $key => $id) {
        updateRecord($id, $meters[$key]);
    }
}
```

This way you are always sure you have accompanying values which you are updating in the db.

PS: this is proof of concept... haven't tested it yet...